# How get delta from single file?

Tags: java, .net, visual-c++

Dropbox is using delta encoding algorithm to find difference between two files, first is modified file and second is old file. But where they are storing old file, how they can find difference because they have only new file, they didn't have old file. It's not possible to firstly download file from server and then find difference, which method they are using?

Comment: You seem to be open minded about which language this should be in.  Care to narrow it down?

Comment: Is this question in the context of implementing something similar? If so, we're going to need a lot more information from you.

Answer (score 0):

according to [this post](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=13313&replies=7#post-93942) by a dropbox employee, it would seem they keep that sort of data resident in memory:

> Dropbox keeps metadata about your files in RAM to prevent expensive
>   database access during syncing. The metadata includes paths to files
>   in your Dropbox, checksums, modification times, etc. We are working
>   hard on making this information more compact and are working on
>   several fronts to improve memory usage. Our techniques are not limited
>   to rewriting pieces of Python and writing custom memory allocators
>   :-).

To do this I would guess they have some sort of special handler that allows them to do the delta diff when the user copies the file into the dropbox folder(s). for that, something like the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class from .Net would do the trick along with your own pass-through shell copy handler (so you can keep a temp copy of the file till the diff is done, if one needs to be done).

Also, as a side note, dropbox is written in python and wxWdigets.

---

some sites you might find useful for delta compression:

- [xdelta](http://code.google.com/p/xdelta/)
- [bsdiff](http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/)
- [wikipedia's page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding)

Comment: Thanks for help. It's so easy to get hash of file in .net and compare hash, but can you please help me to get changed bytes of a file by comparing old and new hash.

Comment: @sukhraj: you wouldn't use the hash to get the changed bytes, only to test for a change, you need to run the delta differential algorithm yourself. Bindiff is basically the program for delta differentals of binaries, but the same method applies to other files types, its open source c (as it was made for a phd thesis). s, but the same method applies to other files types, its open source c (as it was made for a phd thesis).

Comment: Thanks, I can use VCDiff to get changed bytes. I can use it if I've two files old file and modified file, but I've only modified file!

Comment: @Sukhraj: you need to hook the file handler so you can get to the old file before its copied over and diff it against the incoming file, only way I've seen is from the `filesys/minifilter/passthrough` example from the windows DDK

Comment: If user have any file size of 25MB and user click on it for edit. we have not time to copy it before user edit it. Dropbox is not copying file to anywhere else. Can you please find the exact method to do this?

Comment: @Sukhraj: only way I have of finding out is RE, which would be frowned apon. why don't you just mail them, see what they say?